# Phantom characters in strings when converting from Sharepoint > Excel > PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, sharepoint

My organization uses a SP 2010 form to fill information. I didn't build this form, but I've noticed if you try to copy from some of the fields into anywhere else (notepad, etc.) it puts a question mark or euro symbol often directly in front of a string (sometimes in the middle.)

```
Dim objMyList As ListObject
Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
Dim strSPServer As String
Const SERVER As String = "xxx"
Const LISTNAME As String = "{xxx}"
Const VIEWNAME As String = "{xxx}"
strSPServer = "https://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin"
Set objWksheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1"))
```

This part of the script pulls the list of the forms that have already been entered into my worksheet, the equivalent of just using the Export to Excel button on the SP website.

The rest of the sub maps each row to a new PDF by way of using a Replace function on an FDF file. These phantom symbols are nowhere to be found on the Excel sheet. There are no blank spaces or characters of any kind.

```
For i = 2 To lastRow

    oldPDF = "C:\~\Auto.pdf"
    oldFDF = "C:\~\Auto_data.fdf"
    newPDF = "C:\~\" & i & ".pdf"

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open oldFDF For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
        Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
        sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
        Loop
    Close iFileNum

Next i

sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<</T(myFormField)/V( )>>", "<</T(myFormField)/V(" & sht.Range("B" & i) & ")>>")
```

I open up the PDF to find that the phantom characters are back. So what we have so far:

SharePoint form & Excel sheet:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Text from the SP form copied/pasted and on my PDF:

```
?The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I've tried

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "~?", "")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "?", "")
```

But the symbols still show up on the PDF...and it's useless to do a Replace on the Excel sheet itself because the symbols aren't there.

How do I automatically remove these symbols from the PDF/FDF if the above has not worked?

Edit:

```
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, Chr(160), "")
```

Solved the euro symbol issue, but the questions marks remain and I've tried Chr/Chrw(63)

Comment: It's a decent explanation - but can you specify the question you have?

Comment: Edited. I want to automatically remove the symbols from the PDF or the FDF, preferably without invoking a jsObject, I feel like this should be simpler. I will unlikely get the access nor do I have the expertise to fix the source of the issue (the SharePoint site.)